# _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, mobile

I'm trying to get data from api but when i fetch it give an String it not a sub type of map<String,dynamic> how can i solve this here is my model class i don't know where is issue appear i think in the model class but where !! i'm using JsonSerializable package i also make the class nullable to make sure if the data in api returned null and put explicitToJson == true and i didn't solve the problem

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'appointment_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class AppointmentsList {
  final List<Appointment> appointments;

  AppointmentsList({required this.appointments});

  factory AppointmentsList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$AppointmentsListFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AppointmentsListToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Appointment {
  final int id;
  final String appointment_number;
  final int client_id;
  final String appointment_date;
  final int work_shift_id;
  final String appointment_prefer_time;
  final int early_appointment;
  final String? address_notes;
  final int payment_id;
  final String reference_number;
  final int category_id;
  final int address_id;
  final int tech_id;
  final int service_id;
  final int duration;
  final int near_power_slot;
  final int appointment_confirmed;
  final String status;
  final int? appointment_status_id;
  final int? technician_status_id;
  final int? contact_request_id;
  final int subtotal;
  final int total;
  final int tax;
  final String created_at;
  final String updated_at;
  final ServiceModel service;
  final ClientModel client;
  final AddressModel address;
  final List<ProductModel> products;

  Appointment({
    required this.id,
    required this.appointment_number,
    required this.client_id,
    required this.appointment_date,
    required this.work_shift_id,
    required this.appointment_prefer_time,
    required this.early_appointment,
    this.address_notes,
    required this.payment_id,
    required this.reference_number,
    required this.category_id,
    required this.address_id,
    required this.tech_id,
    required this.service_id,
    required this.duration,
    required this.near_power_slot,
    required this.appointment_confirmed,
    required this.status,
    this.appointment_status_id,
    this.technician_status_id,
    this.contact_request_id,
    required this.subtotal,
    required this.total,
    required this.tax,
    required this.created_at,
    required this.updated_at,
    required this.service,
    required this.client,
    required this.address,
    required this.products,
  });

  factory Appointment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$AppointmentFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AppointmentToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class ServiceModel {
  final int? id;
  final String? name;
  final String? service_time;
  final String? status;
  final String? created_at;
  final String? updated_at;

  ServiceModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.service_time,
    this.status,
    this.created_at,
    this.updated_at,
  });

  factory ServiceModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ServiceModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ServiceModelToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class ClientModel {
  final int? id;
  final String? type;
  final String? full_name;
  final String? phone;
  final String? second_phone;
  final int? whatsapp_notifications;
  final String? created_at;
  final String? updated_at;

  ClientModel({
    this.id,
    this.type,
    this.full_name,
    this.phone,
    this.second_phone,
    this.whatsapp_notifications,
    this.created_at,
    this.updated_at,
  });

  factory ClientModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ClientModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ClientModelToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class AddressModel {
  final int? id;
  final int? default_address;
  final int? client_id;
  final int? city_id;
  final int? district_id;
  final int? sector_id;
  final String? name;
  final String? lat;
  final String? long;
  final String? location_note;
  final String? created_at;
  final String? updated_at;

  AddressModel({
    this.id,
    this.default_address,
    this.client_id,
    this.city_id,
    this.district_id,
    this.sector_id,
    this.name,
    this.lat,
    this.long,
    this.location_note,
    this.created_at,
    this.updated_at,
  });

  factory AddressModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$AddressModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AddressModelToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class ProductModel {
  final int? id;
  final int? appointment_id;
  final int? product_id;
  final int? price;
  final int? qty;
  final int? total_price;
  final String? created_at;
  final String? updated_at;
  final ProductDetailModel?
      product; // Assuming ProductDetailModel is defined elsewhere

  ProductModel({
    this.id,
    this.appointment_id,
    this.product_id,
    this.price,
    this.qty,
    this.total_price,
    this.created_at,
    this.updated_at,
    this.product,
  });

  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ProductModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ProductModelToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class ProductDetailModel {
  final int? id;
  final int? category_id;
  final String? name;
  final String? sku;
  final String? description;
  final String? status;
  final int? price;
  final String? notes;
  final int? is_available;
  final int? maintenance_recurring;
  final String? item_code;
  final String? created_at;
  final String? updated_at;

  ProductDetailModel({
    this.id,
    this.category_id,
    this.name,
    this.sku,
    this.description,
    this.status,
    this.price,
    this.notes,
    this.is_available,
    this.maintenance_recurring,
    this.item_code,
    this.created_at,
    this.updated_at,
  });

  factory ProductDetailModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ProductDetailModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ProductDetailModelToJson(this);
 }
```